# How can I make an existing array into a two-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$i=0;
$array=array("one","two");
foreach($array as &$point)
{
   $point[$i]=array($point[$i], $i);
   $i++;
}

var_dump($array);
```

yields:

> **array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "Ane" [1]=> &string(3) "tAo" }**

I was expecting something more like:

> [0]=> [0]=> "one" [1]= 1
>   [1]=> [0]=> "two" [1]= 2

Am I doing the inner block of the `foreach` wrong, or is there another method I should be using to go from a single to a 2D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
$i=1;
$array=array("one","two");
foreach($array as $j => $point)
{
   $array[$j]=array($point, $i);
   $i++;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [1]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array("one","two");
foreach($array as $i => &$point)
{
   $point = array($point, $i + 1);
}

var_dump($array);
```

There were several errors in your code:

1. You should assign to `$point`
2. You should access `$point`, not `$point[$i]`
3. If you had error output turned on (or of you look at the error logs) you'd see `Array to string conversion` error for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to define a two dimensional array in PHP

```
$array = array(
  array(0, 1, 2),
  array(3, 4, 5),
);
```